# Get a reference to an object

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference, cpython, python-object

I am trying to create a class that can be given any object on construction and then will list all of that object's callable methods in an interactive prompt. I am using the `PyInquirer` module for the interactive prompt, and the `inspect` module to get all the methods of the given object.

I have so far succeeded in dynamically building the prompt for any given object, but my program gives the error `Foo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` when attempting to call one of the methods from the prompt.

I think the reason it crashes is that at the time of execution there are no more references to the object, so its reference count is at zero and the object is freed.

If I could get the class to keep hold of its own reference to the object, then this will solve the problem. For example

```
    def __init__(self, object):

        # Create a local reference the object
        self.__object = &object
```

But this is invalid python.

How do I get a reference to the object (or manually increment the reference count, and manually decrement it in the `__del__` function)?

Full source code for ObjectMethodTerminal.py can be found here https://gitlab.com/snippets/1939696

Comment: I think that reference is automatically passed in python; You don't need "&"

Comment: Everything in Python is a reference to an object. That is not your problem. You'll need to tell us more about what exactly it is you're doing with that object so we can help you solve your *actual* problem.

Comment: I think that would just create a copy. So the function pointers from the original would not equal the ones from the copy. So when I try to call the method from the interactive prompt, it will not exist.

Comment: Your example classes listed in `gitlab` don't have proper methods. Use `def Foo(self):`

Comment: Python almost never makes implicit copies. Assignment, argument passing, and return values in particular do not make copies.

Comment: Could you show how you call your `Foo` class in a [minimal standalone code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? your `__init__` class requires 1 argument + self, so `Foo() takes 0 positional arguments` seems wrong.

Comment: @deceze I have linked the code in question. The problem is that I am storing a function in a dict(), and when I later try and call that function I get an error e.g`TypeError: Baz() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: Rewrite your entire question and *show code __here__*. We're not going to speculate about content on another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your sample class to this:

```
class A:
    def Foo(self):
        print("Hello")

    def Bar(self):
        print("World")

    def Baz(self):
        print("!")
```

Note the added `self` to the method parameters.

If you had tried this code first:

```
a = A()
a.Foo()
```

You would have found your error before going the long route of inspecting the class.

Comment: This has solved it, thanks! I will accept the answer once stack overflow allows me to.